# Text mirroring using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When typing text it's want to mirroring other text box.Any modification in this code. 
Is there any import files run this jQuery code?

```js
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
  $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type here:
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="two">
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by mirroring?

Comment: I try to use this my html file and w3school interface file. But this is not working

Comment: Thanks all I got the answer First want to write the HTML query and next write to jQuery

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of `reverse()` function that can be applied on an array

- Create an array from string using `split()`
- Reverse the array using `reverse()`
- Create a string from that array using `join()`

```js
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  $(this).next().val(reverseString(text));
});

function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="two">
```